# Struts : Download xls file with Arabic name doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, struts

I tried to download xls file using Struts 1, it working in Firefox and downloaded the file with Arabic name but not working in Chrome.

Here is the code :

```
public void download(CommandContext context, byte[] data, String filename) {
    String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/unknown";
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context
            .get(context.RESPONSE_KEY);
    try {

        response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
        response.setContentLength(data.length);
        String str = "attachment; filename=\""
                + new String(filename.getBytes("cp1256"), "cp1252") + "\"";
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", str);
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        outputStream.write(data);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).error(
                "Can't download file of newly generated card numbers");

    }

}
```

when I press the download link it downloads like this :

> ØÇáÈÇÊ_ÇáÞÑÂä æÚáæãå.xls

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

Answer (score 1):

`new String(filename.getBytes("cp1256"), "cp1252")` will corrupt the file name when it contains characters that aren't available in `cp1252`. And even when it didn't, then the result is only correct by chance. Don't do this. It's always wrong.

You can find solutions for this in this question: [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)